# How can I pass an argument to a link.typolink for labeling?

Tags: fluid

I want to pass to a link.typolink an argument that a link can be label differently! Which view helper do I need to use to output the argument?

```
<f:if condition="{label}">
            <f:then>
                <f:link.typolink class="info-btn info-btn--{theme}" parameter="{link}" ></f:link.typolink>
            </f:then>
            <f:else>
                    <f:link.typolink class="info-btn info-btn--{theme}" parameter="{link}"><f:translate key="partial.button.Info"/></f:link.typolink>
            </f:else>
        </f:if>
```

Therefore I use an if condition. But how do I best pass the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<f:link.typolink class="info-btn info-btn--{theme}" parameter="{link}" >{label}</f:link.typolink>
```

I set the argument normally. My problem was to empty the cache